# Obfuscating a string that can afterwards be used in a web address

Tags: python-2.7, obfuscation

I have a small simple server in Flask, and I'd like to be able to route to a user's page with the following route:

```
@app.route("/something/<string:username>", methods=["GET"])
```

When it's a clear username it's not a problem, however I want to add simple obfuscation so that when given a key produces a new string that can still be used in a web address.

I tried my luck with several methods I found in Stack Overflow, but the output strings have various issues like non-ASCII characters, or characters that give me issues in the routing (like having a `/` which confuses Flask).

Ideally I'd like to have two functions, `obfuscate(key, string)` and `deobfuscate(key, string)` so I'll be able to use like so:

```
@app.route("/something/<string:username>", methods=["GET"])
def user_page(username):
    # username is an obfuscated string
    clear_username = deobfuscate(MY_KEY, username)
    return flask.make_response("Hi {}".format(clear_username), 200)
...
...
def create_user(username):
    # username is a clear string
    save_to_database(username)
    return obfuscate(MY_KEY, username)
```

To summarize, the obfuscation needs to be simple but good enough that you won't be able to figure it out by looking at the URL, and two-way so that I can figure out what the original string was and print it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue with itsdangerous, which is a dependency of Flask so I have it on my server anyway.

As the example [here](https://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/) shows:

```
>>> from itsdangerous import URLSafeSerializer
>>> s = URLSafeSerializer('secret-key')
>>> s.dumps([1, 2, 3, 4])
'WzEsMiwzLDRd.wSPHqC0gR7VUqivlSukJ0IeTDgo'
>>> s.loads('WzEsMiwzLDRd.wSPHqC0gR7VUqivlSukJ0IeTDgo')
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It's safe to assume I won't have any surprises as the docstring says:

> Works like `:class:Serializer` but dumps and loads into a URL safe string consisting of the upper and lowercase character of the alphabet as well as `_`, `-` and `.`.